# Counting occurence based on condition for each element of a column

Tags: r, count, dataframe, cumulative-sum

I am analysing air traffic movements at an airport. My data set comprises aircraft block off times (leaving the gate) and the respective take-off times.
I am looking for an efficient way to count the (cumulative) occurrence of take-off events based on a condition given by the block-time of a flight.

Being relatively new to R, I have managed to code this by

1. looping over all rows of my data;
2. subsetting the data for the block time (condition event) in that row; and
3. counting the number of rows for the (temporary) data frame.

My solution is pretty slow already for a month of data (~ 50.000 flights), so it will be cumbersome to analyse larger time frames of one or two years.
I failed to find a similar problem on stackoverflow (or elsewhere) that applies to my problem. Neither could I make an `apply()` or `sapply()` work properly.

This is my code:

```
## count depeartures before own off-block
data$CUM_DEPS <- rep(NA, nrow(data))      # initialise column for dep count

for(i in 1:nrow(data)){                   # loop over the data
    data$CUM_DEPS[i] <- nrow(data[data$TAKE_OFF_TIME < data$BLOCK_OFF_TIME[i],])
}
```

Any pointers?

As suggested, this is a snapshot of the data and the result column i created.

```
    FLTID        TAKE_OFF_TIME       BLOCK_OFF_TIME    CUM_DEPS
Flight1  2013-07-01 05:02:42  2013-07-01 04:51:00    0
Flight2  2013-07-01 05:04:30  2013-07-01 04:53:52    0
Flight3  2013-07-01 05:09:01  2013-07-01 04:55:14    0
Flight4  2013-07-01 05:10:30  2013-07-01 05:00:57    0
Flight5  2013-07-01 05:12:58  2013-07-01 05:00:06    0
Flight6  2013-07-01 05:18:45  2013-07-01 05:04:14    1
Flight7  2013-07-01 05:22:12  2013-07-01 05:03:39    1
Flight8  2013-07-01 05:26:02  2013-07-01 05:09:32    3
Flight9  2013-07-01 05:27:24  2013-07-01 05:19:24    6
Flight10 2013-07-01 05:31:32  2013-07-01 05:17:05    5
```

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example with the expected result.

Comment: It sounds like you want `sapply(split(data, data$block), nrow)`

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem (my fault) but for your example `colSums(outer(dat$TAKE_OFF_TIME, dat$BLOCK_OFF_TIME, "<"))` works - but this will run into trouble for larger data. Also `sapply` and `apply` generally wont give you gains in speed of calculation

Comment: Just to check, from your code you have 10 flights here and 100 comparisons - are you comparing every BLOCK_OFF_TIME against every TAKE_OFF_TIME? So with one months flights you will have 50000^2 (2.5e+09) comparisons?

Comment: Thanks, these pointers are really useful and it shows me that I have to learn a lot about R ... I am conscious that my loop / number of comparision is not a good implementation, thus I put this question up here, as I simply could not think up another solution ...I will work with the proposals and let you guys know what works best with my data. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From above code, it seems like you are doing one-to-many comparison.

The thing that makes your code slow is that you are subsetting data based on boolean index
for every single step.

```
data$CUM_DEPS <- rep(NA, nrow(data)) 
take_off_time = data$TAKE_OFF_TIME

for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
    data$CUM_DEPS[i] = sum(data$BLOCK_OFF_TIME[i] > take_off_time)
}
```

This small modification will make it much faster, although I cannot say with an exact
number since I do not have a reproducible example.

The biggest difference is that I store date vector 'take_off_time' rather than
calling from the dataframe for every single iteration, and not subsetting data based on boolean, but summing single boolean.

Above all is from the assumption that you have processed date correctly so that it can be compared with inequality.

Comment: Won782, this one works well. With a month of data, the loop is significantly quicker. I need to find out how to measure this and will post the result here. Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could check where, in-between "TAKE_OFF_TIME"s, each "BLOCK_OFF_TIME" falls. `findInterval` is fast for this; the following looks valid, but maybe you'll have to check `findInterval`'s arguments to suit your exact problem.

```
findInterval(as.POSIXct(DF[["BLOCK_OFF_TIME"]]), 
             as.POSIXct(DF[["TAKE_OFF_TIME"]]))
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 3 6 5
```

And, for the record, the loop using `sapply`:

```
BOT = as.POSIXct(DF[["BLOCK_OFF_TIME"]])
TOT = as.POSIXct(DF[["TAKE_OFF_TIME"]])
sapply(BOT, function(x) sum(TOT < x))
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 3 6 5
```

Where "DF":

```
DF = structure(list(FLTID = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 2L), .Label = c("Flight1", "Flight10", "Flight2", "Flight3", 
"Flight4", "Flight5", "Flight6", "Flight7", "Flight8", "Flight9"
), class = "factor"), TAKE_OFF_TIME = structure(1:10, .Label = c("2013-07-01 05:02:42", 
"2013-07-01 05:04:30", "2013-07-01 05:09:01", "2013-07-01 05:10:30", 
"2013-07-01 05:12:58", "2013-07-01 05:18:45", "2013-07-01 05:22:12", 
"2013-07-01 05:26:02", "2013-07-01 05:27:24", "2013-07-01 05:31:32"
), class = "factor"), BLOCK_OFF_TIME = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
5L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 9L), .Label = c("2013-07-01 04:51:00", 
"2013-07-01 04:53:52", "2013-07-01 04:55:14", "2013-07-01 05:00:06", 
"2013-07-01 05:00:57", "2013-07-01 05:03:39", "2013-07-01 05:04:14", 
"2013-07-01 05:09:32", "2013-07-01 05:17:05", "2013-07-01 05:19:24"
), class = "factor"), CUM_DEPS = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 6L, 5L)), .Names = c("FLTID", "TAKE_OFF_TIME", "BLOCK_OFF_TIME", 
"CUM_DEPS"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexis. I was not aware of findInterval(). I will test this implementation. It may be the answer to another problem I have to address next: counting the take offs of a flight while it taxis. Thus, count the number of other flights take-off events within in taxiout interval (take-off time - block off time for the respective flight).